# Why cannot set value in subscribe method?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I am trying to display a spinner by setting a value, but although it is displayed when setting that value, it does not seen when setting in subscribe method. Is that normal behaviour?

```
search() {
  this.isLoading = true; //when setting at here spinner is working
  fromEvent(this.searchInput.nativeElement, 'keyup').pipe(
    map((event: any) => { // get value
      return event.target.value;
    }),
    filter(res => res.length >= this.minLength),
    debounceTime(this.debounceTime),
    distinctUntilChanged()
  )
  .subscribe(text => {
    this.isLoading = true; //when setting at here spinner is NOT working
    this.demoService.setSubject(text);
    this.isLoading = false;
  });
}
```

Comment: Your `.subscribe(...` sets `this.isLoading = false;` - so of course the spinner is not loading

Comment: Should I set it after `subscribe()` method?

Comment: add a tap operator at the beginning of your pipe where you set isLoading to true instead of inside subscribe which makes the assignment instant and the spinner uncrecognizable.

Comment: I don't know when your loading should start or end, so I can't really help you with that.

Comment: @BerkKurkcuoglu Hi Berk, could you post it by using the given code please?

Comment: @MrkSef It should start before calling demoService and should finish after service call ends. Any idea?

Comment: is `this.demoService.setSubject(text);` asynchronous? Does it return anything like a promise or observable?

Comment: @MrkSef When I use promise it cannot continue to filter. So, I have to use subscribe.

Comment: What can't continue to filter? `.demoService.setSubject` is filtering?

Comment: No, I mean that when typing on the input, it cannot serach after first search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set isLoading true at the beginning of the event instead of waiting for the rxjs sequence to be completed, when you set it inside the subscription then just set it false 2 lines after it is almost an atomic operation which makes the spinner unrecognizable by human eye.

```
search() { 
  fromEvent(this.searchInput.nativeElement, 'keyup').pipe(
    tap(() => this.isLoading = true),
    map((event: any) => { // get value
      return event.target.value;
    }),
    filter(res => res.length >= this.minLength),
    debounceTime(this.debounceTime),
    distinctUntilChanged()
  )
  .subscribe(text => {     
    this.demoService.setSubject(text);
    this.isLoading = false;
  });
}
```

Comment: Perfect... Thanks a lot. What tap operator exactly do or used?

Comment: Tap was known as 'do' priorly, it is just to execute a function like a side effect in this case, without any real change in the pipe chain.